# How to allocate and return a string without memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, return-value

Let's say I have 3 functions:

```
int A(void); 
string B(const string& fileName); 
void C(string& dataFromFile);
```

A() calls B() and uses B()'s return value as an input parameter to C(). In this case, I want to open the file in B() and read the data written in the file to a buffer. Then I want to return this data as a string. How can I implement B() to avoid memory leak? Because the pseudo-code below would cause memory leak.

```
string B(const string& fileName) {
    // open file 
    char* buffer = new char[sizeOfFile];
    // read from file and assogn the data to buffer
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Stay with `std::string` or `char *`.  Don't mix them or you get the issues you are facing (and more).  You can read the file into a `std::string`, which would resolve your issue; or declare the function to return `char *`.

Comment: Create a return value string explicitly from the buffer, then delete the buffer. The string's buffer is independent of the ctor argument.

Comment: The file is *definitely* full text? There are multiple ways to do this, [this being one](http://pastebin.com/Ls2Wpejs).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use std::string which avoid any leaks.

```
std::string B(const std::string& fileName)
{
std::string buffer;
// open file
buffer.reserve(sizeOfFile);
// do stuff
return buffer;
}
```

EDIT : With the use of reserve which preallocates the needed memory and [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) this should not have huge performance lose compared to char*.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the middleman. Start with a string, read into the string, and return the string. I'm not sure which functions you are using to read your data, but whatever you can do with a `char*`, you can do with a `std::string`. For example, if you are using the `read` function of an `ifstream`, you can do this:

```
std::string buffer;
buffer.resize(sizeOfFile);
fin.read(&buffer[0], sizeOfFile);
return buffer;
```

Comment: So is it safe to say that this version does not cause any memory leak, as well as the memory allocated for the buffer will be released automatically?
Another question: (I am trying to understand the underlying mechanisms) What is special about std::string? What happens for example when I am programming for an embedded platform, or for any platform where they defined another string?

Comment: @lulijeta: Nothing is particularly special about `std::string`. It just has a destructor which cleans up any resources that it allocates, as any well behaved class should. That is, it follows [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Answer (score -1):

Update the function to:

```
string B(const string& fileName) {
    // open file 
    char* buffer = new char[sizeOfFile];
    // read from file and assogn the data to buffer

    string ret(buffer);
    delete [] buffer;
    return ret;
}
```

If you can use a `string` instead of a `char*`, it will be still better.

```
string B(const string& fileName) {
    // open file 

    strin ret(sizeOfFile, `\0');
    // read from file and assogn the data to ret

    return ret;
}
```